# Create a dict from combinations in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, combinations

I'm trying to create a `dict` from all possible pairs of elements in a list. This is what I've tried.

```
>>from itertools import combinations
>>l = ['a','b','c']
>>dict(combinations(l,2))
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'c'}
```

This is wrong, as there are 3 possible combinations. It's missing `'a': 'b'`. When I `list(combinations(l,2))` however, it gives me all possible combinations:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. `{'a': 'b'}` was overwritten by `{'a': 'c'}`

Comment: You can use the following: `print ([(i, j) for i in l for j in l if i<j])` with the answer as `[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]`

Comment: @Bazingaa I think you've missed the point they are trying to make. The list of tuples is to illustrate that the pairing does exist, but it doesn't end up in the final dictionary, which is due to the duplicate key issue I mentioned

Comment: Hmm, I see. That's true. Nevertheless I will leave my comment as it gives an alternate to combinations for this specific list `l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` in order to create a mapping to a list of values:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, *v in combinations(l, 2):
...     d[k].extend(v)
... 
>>> dict(d)
{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['c']}
```